# I have 2 MySQL tables, how do I count rows from the one table and add that to a SELECT query against the other table?

Tags: mysql

here are the two MySQL tables and their columns:

| 'classIndex' Table | 'classStudent' Table |
| --- | --- |
| classID | classStudentID |
| subjectTitle | classID |
| subjectLevel | studentID |
| syllabusCode | subjectID |
| classIdentifier | teacherID |
| subjectGroup |  |
| createdAt |  |
| updatedAt |  |

'classIndex' holds 1 row per class, 'classStudent' holds all the students for each class. 1-to-many relationship between classIndex and classStudent

What I would like to achieve is a count of the number of students in each class (from classStudent) joined to the SELECT query run against 'classIndex' (see queries below). Resulting in one results that has the classes as well as the student count for each class.

As far as individual queries go, I have the following:

```
SELECT classID, subjectTitle, subjectLevel, syllabusCode, classIdentifier, subjectGroup, createdAt, updatedAt FROM classIndex WHERE teacherID = 1;
```

```
SELECT classID, COUNT(classID) AS 'classSize' FROM classStudent WHERE teacherID = 1 GROUP BY classID;
```

The individual query do exactly what I need them to do, I just don't know how to combine the results of these queries (I tried joining on classID, too ambiguous). It's not a distinct count, the count groups based on classID.

Comment: You were on the right track. Join and look into GROUP BY. Also: You don't want to insert, which could result in the count getting out of sync (look into [redundancy](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-problem-of-redundancy-in-database/)). Just use the join unless you are huge in scale and know what you're doing and have a VERY good reason to do it.

Comment: Hi @RobIII, how would you suggest I approach that? (Just started with MySQL so I'm not too sure how the complex queries are written)

Comment: StackOverflow is not for complete, on demand, personalised tutorials. Try looking stuff up like [joins](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) and [group by](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
SELECT ci.classID, ci.teacherID, ci.subjectTitle, ci.subjectLevel, ci.syllabusCode, ci.classIdentifier, ci.subjectGroup, ci.createdAt, ci.updatedAt, COUNT(cs.classID) AS 'classSize'
FROM classIndex ci
LEFT JOIN classStudent cs 
ON cs.classID = ci.classID
WHERE ci.teacherID = 1
GROUP BY ci.classID;
```

Hope it helps anyone with a similar issue.

Comment: Your group-by is incomplete. It should have **all** fields that are **not** in an aggregate (like `count`, `sum`, `avg` etc). MySQL is known for not giving a crap about this, but you should.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! I'll made the change @RobIII